# Foreach color tabla y ordenar

Tags: laravel, foreach, blade

Estoy trabajando con laravel y blade... necesito mostrar una simple tabla pero realmente no se me ocurre como hacerlo.

Tengo en el controlador

Un modelo que carga una tabla que tiene...

Dia Hora precio y demas datos sin importancia...

De momento puedo mostrar la tabla ordenada por hora... o por precio sin problema..

Lo que necesito hacer es... que la tabla esté dividida en 3 colores... las 8 horas más baratas en color verde las 8 siguientes en color amarillo y las 8 restantes más caras en rojo...

Pero... que la tabla la muestre ordenada por hora... osea la tabla estaría 00... 01... 02 03 etc y tengan el color según el rango de precio..

Alguien seria tan amable de darme una idea me trae mal esto.

Comment: Nosotros no damos ideas así nomás. Primero, demuestranos que sos parte del esfuerzo por responder tu propia duda con un [ejemplo minimo, completo y verificable](/help/minimal-reproducible-example) de alguno de tus intentos por resolver tu propia duda. Lecturas recomendadas: [como preguntar?](/help/how-to-ask), [Te he votado negativamente porque no intentaste nada](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2874/) y [Te he votado negativamente porque pides directamente que hagan tu trabajo/tarea escolar](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4320)

Answer (score 0):

Sin ver el código poco podemos hacer...

Pero se me ocurre que en tu colección de datos añadas un valor:

```
  $model->color = 'Red'; o en hexadecimal #ff0000
```

Y según vas pintando la tabla con el foreach que tengas, aplicar el color que tengas en ese modela en la fila en la que esta.